# load google map on dynamic latitude / longitude in bootstrap modal

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bootstrap-modal

I am facing issue with google maps. Actually I have a listing page where every row have map button to show map for lat/long for that particular row.

I am using jQuery ajax call to open popup where a div

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
function showMap(id) {
   $("#map .modal-body").load("/showmap?id=" + id, function() { 
      $("#map").modal("show");
      return false; 
   });
}
```

While showmap template have map show code like

```
loadMap();

function loadMap() {

    var latitude = <?php echo $latitude ?>;
    var longitude = <?php echo $longitude ?>;

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-body'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 21.0000, lng: 78.0000}
    });

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Location'
        });

    $('#map').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        var center = map.getCenter();
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
}
```

That is working fine. However to reduce main page load time , I need to include maps script inclusion at popup that generate issue because subsequent maps libs not loaded and code gave error.

I found solution for remove inclusion from main page and add following code at popup which define callback for map code ( which needed for deferred execution of my map code after all libs load )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=loadMap", function() {
        // No code here
     });
});
```

But then I got google map multiple inclusion error. **"You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors."**

If someone have idea how it could be resolved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like not a very real solution exist. But I did one hack for doing this.

First I moved code back to my view file and set callback to cutom function instead of map function like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&callback=checkLoading", function() {
        // No code here
    });
});
var mapEnabled = false;

function checkLoading {
    mapEnabled = true;
}
```

In Map Loading function add a check only when mapEnabled is true then load popup which have map loading code/ui.

```
function loadMap(id) {
    if(mapEnabled == true) { 
        $("#map .modal-body").load("/showmap?id=" + id, function() { 
            $("#map").modal("show");
            return false; 
        });
    } else {
        $('.top-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>  Map is loading... Please wait and click again later.</div>');
    } 
}
```